# Python logical operator or

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
p = "string", "string2"
s = None
if p != None or  s !=  None:
    r = p + s
```

I would like to execute `p+s` if one of these two conditions is not `None`. But I get a concatenation error: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "NoneType") to tuple`

I'll try to be more clearly. I'm using python in 3D application. So the variables are for storing some 3D object's names. P is for polygonal objects and S is for nurbsSurface objects. In some cases in the 3D scene maybe not exists one of those objects. So the variable returns None. I need to store in variable R either S or P or both of them.

Comment: Python requires indentation: you need to put spaces before the line inside the conditional block. Also, paste the error you are getting.

Comment: ...and the error message in this case is pretty clear enough in my opinion: **can only concatenate tuple (not "NoneType") to tuple**.

Comment: what do you mean by "execute `p+s`"? What value do you want `r` to have?

Comment: on a side note you should use `if p is not None`

Comment: Please,  indicate how shoul I edit the question to fit the rules? I already get my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the various comments, it looks like you rather want something like:

```
if p is not None or s is not None:
    r = (p or ()) + (s or ())
```

One could instead use `if/else` expressions, but this simpler one should suffice.

Still, for the pedants among us,

```
    r = (() if p is None else p) + (() if s is None else s)
```

would be a fully-coded-out variant.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you! I thought it was list and not tuple

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't allow you to concatenate tuples which are None.
In your example the variable "s" is None and so the line `r = p + s` gives you a concatenation error. You should change your code as shown below:

```
p = "string", "string2"
s = None
if p and s:
    r = p + s
elif p:
    r = p
else:
    r = s
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by `execute p+s`, but the concatenation error is totally reasonable.

`python` does not allow adding None to tuples. My understanding is that you need to seamlessly set r either p, s, or both:

Note: edited after misinterpretation, also using a set solution, which seems like it may be suitable for your purposes since you don't have a need for duplicates, and you haven't indicated that order is important, it also allows for a solution that I find slightly cleaner.

```
p = "string", "string2"
s = None
r = p or set() | s or set()
```

Also, based on your explanation it doesn't seem that you actually need the if statement as the result will always contain one of them. Let me know if that's not correct though.

Comment: I'll try to be more clearly. I'm using python in 3D application. So the variables are for storing some 3D object's names. P is for polygonal objects and S is for nurbsSurface objects. In some cases in the 3D scene maybe not exists one of those objects. So the variable returns None. I need to store in variable R either S or P or both of them.

Comment: @iRex please update your question with this information. Also, are p and s supposed to be either strings or `None`? (or do they directly contain 3d objects?) Why is `p` a tuple in your example?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I realize that's strange, which is why I mentioned. Was slow to update, but it appears my interpretation was indeed incorrect.